# how to share functions across controllers in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular.js.
   I have an app which contains few tabs with different pages. Each page is maintained by different controller to manage its own data. My doubt is, how to use same functions across different pages (controllers). For example,
fields of different pages would have same validation functions, formatting functions and many other util functions.

1.How to maintain functions common across different controllers?
2.How to bind common functions as listeners to the events that are bound to the fields of different pages (managed by different controllers) as they don't share scope?
Thanks.

Comment: Answer to first question would be to use services. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

For the second one you should probably take a look at directives https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use a Factory or a Service**

To share functions across different controllers you can use a factory or a service. an example will show this better

**Controller & Factory**

This is an example from the Angular JS documentation. the factory can be used anywhere it is injected into the function.

```
angular.
module('myServiceModule', []).
controller('MyController', ['$scope','notify', function ($scope, notify) {
   $scope.callNotify = function(msg) {
     notify(msg);
   };
}]).
factory('notify', ['$window', function(win) {
  var msgs = [];
  return function(msg) {
    msgs.push(msg);
    if (msgs.length == 3) {
      win.alert(msgs.join("\n"));
      msgs = [];
    }
  };
}]);
```

See in the function on the controller there is an injection of `notify` this could be called in another controller if you so wished.

**Directives**

You should also take a look at directives, they let you write your own html tags or attributes. These can be reused on different pages.

**Example Directive**

Here is the actual Directive code

```
app.directive('appInfo', function() { 
  return { 
    restrict: 'E', 
    scope: { 
      info: '=' 
    }, 
    templateUrl: 'js/directives/appInfo.html' 
  }; 
});
```

`restrict: E` means that it will be used as an element not an attribute.

`scope` lists the different scopes available to the element.

`templateUrl` this links to where you store your html snippet.

Here is the Directive html snippet

```
<img class="icon" ng-src="{{ info.icon }}"> 
<h2 class="title">{{ info.title }}</h2> 
<p class="developer">{{ info.developer }}</p> 
<p class="price">{{ info.price | currency }}</p>
```

See that we have access to the `info` from scope

Below see the directive as a tag in our main html, you can put this into the index page or any of your templates as many times as you like.

```
<div class="card"> 
  <app-info info="move"></app-info> 
</div>
```

Thats the basics of building a directive, this one only has html and scope but you can make much more complex ones that use controllers.

**Extra note for study**

Take some time to go through the [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/en/courses/learn-angularjs) AngularJS tutorials, they are free and only take 2 nights of work tops. They also explain all of the basics of Angular JS like directives, controllers, services etc.

Comment: For example, if we see, onclick="return maskField(this, event)", I use this on every input field of different pages. How to achieve this in ang.js? I mean, how to bind maskField() to different fields of different pages in angular js? Thanks.

Comment: @Ramson that's a directive, if its some reusable html you want.

Comment: @Ramson I'll add an example Directive now. But codecademy can give you more detail.

Comment: Can you kindly provide me an example/link to use directive to make use of a html code snippet on many html elements. I read that directives are for reusing elements rather than snippets. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Ramson if you would like to use is on several regular elements use that in your directive.html or make the `restrict: 'A';` this lets you declare your directive as an attribute you can add to other tags, But I'm afraid thats where my knowledge gets a bit weaker as I have not done it. I hope I was able to help you a bit at least. Good luck

Answer (score 3):

That what [services/factories](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) are for.

They provide singleton "classes" that contain whatever data and functions you want to share across the app.

For example:

```
app.factory('myService', function() {
  return {
    doSomethingCool: doSomethingCool
  };
});

app.controller('myController', function(myService) {
  myService.doSomethingCool();
});
```

There are some minor differences between factories and services, so you'll have to look into those (that's a bit out of the scope of this question).